# How to generate a random number that is different from an existing number?

Tags: c#

I know this question sounds like a duplicate, but I haven't found an answer to it yet. Let me know, thanks.

For example:
a = 50
b = random

But b can never be the same as a

Comment: you can just generate 'b' randomly, and if it has the same value as 'a', try it again ;)

Comment: Or just increment the value if it's the same as `a`, having reduced your upper bound by 1 to start with.

Comment: Or set range to generate random number that doesn't contain `a`.

Comment: @Jon: _"Or just increment the value if it's the same as a"_ -- do you not mean "if it's equal to or greater than a"?

Comment: We have lots of examples of different ways to generate random numbers where certain numbers are excluded. See marked duplicates; the "from a range" ones are most applicable, where the excluded range is just the single value `a` you have.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Yes, I do. Oops :)

Comment: Use a loop and keep looping until the values are different

Comment: @JonSkeet if you increment the value when it's the same as a... wouldn't that double the chance of 'a+1' being generated? I mean, 'a+1' would be generated when 'a' is generated and when 'a+1' is generated too... that doubles its probabilities, so it doesn't seem random enough for me :)

Comment: @DIe: That's why I agreed with Peter's correction - you increment the value for any value greater than or equal to `a`.

Comment: Oops didn't see that, great!